# python property setter without specify argument

Tags: python, properties, getter-setter

I'm sure this question as already been answer, i apologised in advance.
I wish to create a data type that can be either a numpy array or pandas dataframe.

```py
@dataclass
class DataType:
    """
    dataclass containing the data as either a matrix or dataframe
    """
    _data: Optional[np.ndarray | pd.DataFrame] = None

    @property
    def data(self) -> Optional[np.ndarray | pd.DataFrame]:
        """property to set data values

        Returns:
            np.ndarray | pd.DataFrame: values in either matrix or dataframe
        """
        return self._data

    @data.setter
    def data(self, val: np.ndarray | pd.DataFrame) -> None:
        self._data = val
```

but i would like to use the setter without specify the `data` parameter

```py
d: dict[str, DataType] = field(default_factory=dict)
# edited : removed 'd["key"] = DataType()' for the line above
d["key"] = np.array(...)
# instead of - d["key"].data = np.array(...)
```

maybe properties are not the best solution for this.

Comment: You can't do this, as this is a syntax for assigning completely different object. It would no longer be a `DataType()`.

Comment: yes, that makes sense. How about if I initiate the variable `d` with the field method? I guess that won't change anything

Comment: You are trying to change the fundamental behaviour of assignment in Python. Even if that would be possible, that's a bad idea. Typing `.data` isn't that much of an added effort anyway.

Comment: It's not really an issue of effort, but maybe of technical debt, as this is called at a lot of places in the code. So it's just a question of how i can improve it without a lot of changes elsewhere.

Comment: This would make your technical debt even worse, as anyone reading the code would have to know that it is not a regular assignment happening there. Anyway, maybe you don't need DataClass there at all? Maybe `d['key'] = DataClass().data` would be enough?